# BackgroundWorker vs NotifyPropertyChanged issue

Tags: wpf, thread-safety, backgroundworker

I have WPF application that performs some calculations in BackgroundWorker. The problem is that when I try to update property (which calls NotifyPropertyChanged in setter) in RunWorkerCompleted event handler I get InvalidOperationException - `The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.`

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx) says that BackgroundWorker handles thread synchronization itself so I shouldn't care about using Dispatcher. But I see that it doesn't handle NotifyPropertyChanged correctly.

Can anybody help me with this issue?

**EDIT**

Here is my code (sorry for some irrelevant features):

```
backgroundWorker.DoWork += delegate(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs args)
                                           {
                                               var action = (Func<Bitmap>) args.Argument;
                                               args.Result = BitmapUtil.BitmapSourceFromBitmap(action());
                                           };

backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
                                                       {
                                                           if (args.Cancelled || (args.Error != null))
                                                           {
                                                               return;
                                                           }

                                                           ImageProcessed = (BitmapSource) args.Result;
                                                       };

...

public BitmapSource ImageProcessed
        {
            get { return imageProcessed; }

            set
            {
                imageProcessed = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(VMUtil.GetNameOf<ImageAnalyzerViewModel>(vm => vm.ImageProcessed));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please show some code on how you are setting the property.  The article is a little misleading, in that objects in the DoWork function are in another thread, and cannot be used directly outside the thread.

Answer (score 1):

The problem's not being caused by any code in `RunWorkerCompleted`.  That code runs on the same thread that created the `BackgroundWorker`.  The problem's in the method that's actually being run in the background.

Hard to say what that problem might be without seeing that code.  The fact that you're silently discarding any errors that the method throws, instead of logging or reporting what's in `args.Error`, may enter into the problem too.

Comment: But if I comment line where property is updated (ImageProcessed = (BitmapSource) args.Result;) or even OnPropertyChanged call, everything works fine.

Comment: Oh, duh.  You're creating the `BitmapSource` on the background thread, and it's a `DispatcherObject` and so has thread affinity.  You may be able to make the problem go away by calling `Freeze` on the `BitmapSource`; if not, you may have to create the actual `BitmapSource` object (which presumably isn't the slow-running part of the operation) in `RunWorkerCompleted`.

Comment: But how can you explain that everything works fine if I don't call OnPropertyChanged?

Comment: Raising PropertyChanged makes the UI thread try to access the object.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a matter of cross-thread issue try this:

```
public BitmapSource ImageProcessed         
{             
    get
    { 
        return imageProcessed; 
    }              
    set         
    {                 
         imageProcessed = value;   
         // bring the following to the main thread
         Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
         {
            OnPropertyChanged(VMUtil.GetNameOf<ImageAnalyzerViewModel>(vm => vm.ImageProcessed));   
          }); 

  }         
}
```